# Redirect the password prompt alert

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, dropbear

Is it possible to redirect password prompt alert to a file or silence it?

`[lnx51 ~]$ ssh root@192.168.1.1
root@192.168.1.1's password:`

Comment: Do you want that doesnt ask password and plan to use a id_rsa or something like that? or are you asking to automate put the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid password authentication you can use next sentence:

```
  ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no root@192.168.1.1
```

This disable 'manual' authentication but you need another method to login, if not you will get an error like that:

```
  Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Maybe you have some issue with your id_rsa

If you want to use with rsync (as your example) you must put command with quotes ("):

```
   rsync -v -r -l -e "ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no"  ctxt root@192.168.6.2:/home/
```

You can check rsync options at [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Comment: With direct ssh it works but with rsync it fails. Anything I'm missing?thanks.
`[lnx5 ~]$ rsync -v -r  -l -e ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no  ctxt root@192.168.6.2:/home/
root@192.168.6.2's password:`

Answer (score 1):

Use batchmode to prevent ssh from prompting for passwords etc esp if you are running via rsync. (I am assuming you will set up passphrase based authentication)

```
ssh -o BatchMode=yes root@hostname command
```

Comment: I still see the prompt. Does dropbear ssh doesn't support the batchmode option?
`lnx~#rsync -v -r -l  -e ssh -o BatchMode
=yes -i /root/ssh/id_rsa -y -y samp.txt root@10.1.13.1:/home/
root@10.1.13.1's password:`